# OpenMPI: multi-host usage

Tags: ssh, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I have two hosts with passwordless SSH-connection: 10.XXX.XXX.XX1 and 10.XXX.XXX.XX2;

I have a simple binary file "matrix_mult", which executes successfully (`mpirun matrix_mult`).

Now I want to use it in multi-host mode and try the following:

`mpirun -H 10.XXX.XXX.XX1,10.XXX.XXX.XX2 matrix_mult`

But it returns "10.0.0.0: Connection timeout"

I also tried to use hostfile with same hosts, but result was the same...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `10/8` is a private network, so there is no point in obfuscating the IP addresses. Are these two physical hosts with no firewall running? or two VM/containers in a Kubernetes cluster? Also, please copy/paste the full error message.

Comment: Thanks for answer, @GillesGouaillardet!
We have a kind of firewall in these hosts. But SSH already works great... Does it makes any sense for MPI network execution?

Comment: `SSH` is only used to spawn the `orted` daemons. Then the daemons communicate via the `oob/tcp` component (read, an other socket connection), and then the MPI apps communicate via the `btl/tcp` components (read other socket(s) connections(s)). You can refer to https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=tcp#tcp-selection for some more details.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, I understand. So about full log of error: there was no return except for connection timeout after ~5 mins of connection trying. It seems like MPI couldn't make any connection between hosts at all.